# Can ios icloud backups restore to a device after exchange activesync remote wipe?

Tags: ios, icloud, backup, exchange-activesync

Seeing as it is apparently the case that reading an office365/exchange e-mail account on one's ios device [enables whoever runs the server to wipe one's whole device at will](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment-reference-ios/integration-features-apd81ad3352f/1/web/1) --- if this happens to someone, can they restore their data from an icloud backup, or does activesync remote wipe somehow destroy backups as well?

Comment: How would that happen, exactly?  Does your organization have access to Apple's servers?  What I'd expect to happen is that you'd restore the backup, the phone would check in with the Exchange server, and the phone would potentially get erased again.  I'm not an Exchange admin, don't know if such a command is persistent for some interval.

Comment: Who knows how that would happen?  For that matter, who knows whether or not these organizations have 'access' to Apple servers the same way they have surprise 'access' to iOS devices.  If Apple writes software to allow organizations to wipe an entire phone (apparently by deleting the cryptographic keys associated with its data) as punishment for the mistake of using a Microsoft email account, why wouldn't it also cause that same software to wipe associated iCloud backups?

Comment: (Interesting point about phoning home to exchange, also!  If that's how wipes work, then maybe they could be prevented by, eg, connecting the device through a pi-hole or something to prevent unauthorized network calls.)

Comment: You agreed to the imposition of the organization's security policy when you added the Exchange account to your phone... no idea why you think it would be a "surprise".  When someone leaves us who was doing BYOD, we always advise them to remove the Exchange account from their phone before their separation is finished.

Comment: if the employee or other organization member is actually notified of this policy.  how many organizations that use the now-ubiquitous Microsoft accounts actually inform people of their capacity or ostensible right to delete personal data from the devices of people who use their e-mail?

Comment: Not necessary.  The device tells you if there is a security policy that will be applied, and you either agree to it, and the add succeeds, or you do not, and the add fails.